# Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a non-constant continuous such that $f\circ f=f.$ Define $E_f=\{x\in[0,1]: f(x)=x\}.$ Is $E_f $ closed or open?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a non-constant continuous such that $f\circ f=f.$ Define $E_f=\{x\in[0,1]: f(x)=x\}.$ Is $E_f $
>
> 1. Empty
> 2. Closed or open
> 3. An interval

My attempt so far:

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x.$ We note that, $g$ is continuous.

Also,  $g(0)=f(0)\geq 0$ and $g(1)=f(1)-1\leq 0$ hence by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $\exists x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $g(x_0)=f(x_0)-x_0=0$ hence $x_0\in E_f=\{x \in [0,1] : f(x)=x \}.$

If $E_f=\{x_0\}$ then we are done.

Otherwise, $E_f\neq \phi,\{x\}.$

This means, that if, $x,y \in E_f$ such that $x\neq y,$  then we may assume, $x\lt y$ (WLOG).

For any $z\in [x,y],\exists t\in [0,1]$ such that $z=(1-t)x+ty.$

We have $f(x)=x\leq z \leq y=f(y).$

By the Intermediate Value Theorem  there is $s\in [0,1]$ such that $f(s)=z$, but since $f(f(s))=f(s)=z$, we get $f(z)=z.$

This means, $z\in E_f\implies [x,y]\subseteq E_f.$

From here, we can claim that $E_f$ is an interval.

---

- Can I directly claim that $E_f$ is an interval as I did above?
- This is the point, where I am stuck as I don't understand how to prove/disprove $E_f$ is closed or open. Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: $E_f$ is closed because it is the vanishing set of the continuous function $g(x)=f(x)-x$.

Comment: @Zerox I think I need a bit more elaboration ?

Comment: Can you prove that the vanishing set of a continuous function is closed?

Comment: @Zerox I don't know what is the "vanishing set of a continuous function". Is it $V=\{x:f(x)=0\}$, where $f$ is the continuous function ? If so, then no, I haven't proved till now that $V$ is closed.

Comment: Then try to prove the following result: If $g:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ is continuous, then $\{ x \in [0,1] \mid g(x)=0 \}$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]$. *(Hint: If $g(x_n)=0$ and $x_n \rightarrow x$, what can we say about $g(x)$?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired from @Koro 's idea, here is the proof:

We know that, closed sets are complements of open sets.

So, preimages under a continuous map of closed sets are closed since, the pre image of an open set under a continuous map is open.

So $E_f$ in the original post is $g^{-1}(\{0\})$, where $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and as $\{0\}$ is closed so, $E_f$ is closed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm familiar with a general results that given $f,g:X\to Y$ continuous function, if $Y$ is Hausdorff than $C =\{ x \in X: f(x) = g(x) \}$ is closed (if needed I can provide a proof). Since you don't specify that I think we are working with euclidean topology so $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff. This will respond easily at the second point.